# Using perl on the web

Tags: html, perl, .htaccess

Does my .htaccess file not containing

> "Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
>
> AddHandler cgi-script .plx"

have something to do with my perl scripts not running on my friends web server which he allocated me a sub domain on?

Also does it have anything to do with not being in the root? apparently i'm somewhere like \Public_html\plugins\jack\

html from which i'm trying to call the perl script from:

```
<html> 
<!--#exec cgi="cgi-bin/print.pl"-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/cgi-bin/print.pl" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Run this!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
BEGIN {
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
die ’Some disaster!’; # This will be printed to the browser
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

}
```

note: when I open the shtml file this I get "[an error occurred while processing this directive]" and when i click "run this" i get

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@whatever.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If any additional information is required, please ask. I'm not sure if showing the contents of my htaccess file to the whole world is retarded or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend replacing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Make sure the file permissions for your `cgi-bin` folder and the `print.pl` script are set to `755`
When you upload this script, be sure it's in `ASCII` mode.

As for the `404 Not Found error` goes, ErrorDocument does not exist where it was specified, so it causes this error.

Do you have access to your server log? If yes, then it will be recorded in the log. Also, who created the `cgi-bin` folder? Did you or your hosting provider? Note that `cgi-bin` folder is set up as a `ScriptAlias` in the configuration file.  Every file in that directory will be treated as a script and executed upon request.

Comment: Well, I would use warnings; but it wasn't part of the snippet in the book i'm reading. I read that I should be uploading perl files in binary and not ASCII. I don't think I have access to server log, my friend has just had an operation, so I can't contact him at the moment, but when I can I'll ask him about it. I didn't make cgi-bin, so it was either automated or my friend made it. I will ask him to change the permissions of the file and folder, but he said that 777 was world-executable permission. Thank you for your answer!